# Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type but prints with "optional"

Tags: html, json, swift, xcode, url

First off before anybody puts a cheeky "duplicate question" post. I have gone through EVERY single one on stack and then some. The similar posts have either been inapplicable or haven't worked for me.

Background:

I am trying to build an app to communicate with a website (server down the road, one step at a time.) I have established communication and verified that it works. Long and the short of it, the data coming in when printed has an "optional" in front of it.

My website is very barebones and is made up of an html and js file. The js is linked to my html via <"script"> command. I am trying to us a JSONdecode in swift but am prompted with a "not valid JSON" error. When I investigated further I am getting the previously mentioned "optional" in my data. I tried using "!" to force unwrap my incoming data but am prompted with "cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type"??? When I try my swift code with a known JSON website (something I found on youtube) it works fine.

Obviously my question isn't exclusive to "force unwrap." The solution provided may change what is necessary to rectify this ie. change what the question "should have been." I am open to any and all solutions but maybe we'll just start with how can I force unwrap this?

Thank you in advance.

XCODE (Swift)

```
super.viewDidLoad()

let url = URL(string: "https://*****for my eyes only*****.com/script.js")!              

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
     guard let data = data,
     let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
     error == nil else 
           {                                           
              print("error", error ?? "Unknown error")
                       return
           }

     guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else 
           {               
              print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
              print("response = \(response)")
                       return
           }


//shows data printed w/ optional in front of data                   
let htmlcontent = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

print(htmlcontent)


//data is the portion I am trying to force unwrap 
//currently produces error "not valid JSON"      
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let classes = try! decoder.decode([Class].self, from: data)
```

HTML Code

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Code (Taken from internet - Not Mine)

```
{
    "mothmap": {
        "value": [
            {
                "longitude": -0.13025200000004133,
                "latitude": 51.4596619
            },
            {
                "longitude": -2.707384100000013,
                "latitude": 53.7613383
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Change to `print(htmlcontent!)` and tell us what it says

Comment: The HTML is completely unnecessary, but it also looks like you aren’t loading it. You need to load the JS directly, but it looks like you are doing that

Comment: Also, don’t use POST.

Comment: You are seeing a non-optional string that had an optional string interpolated inside of it. It is too late at that point

Comment: @LouFranco Thank you for your timely response. I changed to ```print(htmlcontent!)``` and it did remove the optional. the html is unnecessary you are right. I forgot I had taken it out of the process by updating my swift url address to source the js file directly to help with troubleshooting. What would you recommend instead of using post? Also is it viable to just use the html content command to process data instead of JSONdecode? Most online references suggest JSON methods.

Comment: If you see HTML, then it’s not JSON and you can’t decode it

Comment: Swift will not look for a script tag there and get the JSON. You need to send JSON data directly

Comment: Just don’t set any method. The default is GET, which is correct

Comment: Show us what printed. There is probably a syntax error in the JSON

Comment: {
    "mothmap": {
        "value": [
            {
                "longitude": -0.13025200000004133,
                "latitude": 51.4596619
            },
            {
                "longitude": -2.707384100000013,
                "latitude": 53.7613383
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: This is with the ! after htmlcontent

Comment: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/michaelszabo/Desktop/JSON/JSON/ViewController.swift, line 74
2020-01-17 21:03:40.984097-0500 JSON[1356:79560] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:

Comment: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/michaelszabo/Desktop/JSON/JSON/ViewController.swift, line 74
(lldb)

Comment: and the error for the JSONdecode portion

Answer (score 1):

The error says

> Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.

This is true. Your JSON is not an array, but you passed an array type `[Class]` to the decoder. You need to match the type to the JSON.

Try

```
let classes = try! decoder.decode(Class.self, from: data)
```

Or edit the JSON to put the class in `[]`

```
[{
    "mothmap": {
        "value": [
            {
                "longitude": -0.13025200000004133,
                "latitude": 51.4596619
            },
            {
                "longitude": -2.707384100000013,
                "latitude": 53.7613383
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

Comment: so I just tried that and it gives me an error. HOWEVER that error is just associated with the tag struct I have set up not matching with that data I asked for. ie. No more "invalid JSON" error.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to help with this sir.